# find unique first top and bottom lines of fastq file from fasta file

Tags: python, unix, awk, grep, fastq

I have 2 files one is `fasta` file and other one is `fastq` file.  I want to take the `fasta`, read each line and search each line in the `fastq` file and print top line and bottom lines.  This is what I have

**fasta file**

> read1
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGA
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGG

```
for seq in `cat sequences`;do grep -A 2 -B 1 $seq FAP.1.txt;done
```

> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1107:20386:6577 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC
>
> +
>
> CCCFFFFFHGHHHJIJHFDDDB173@8815BDDB###############
>
> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1114:5718:53821 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> +
>   ;@?DBD<@@FFHHH<
>
> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1209:10703:35361 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> +
>
> @@@FFFFFHGHHHGIJHFDDDDDBDD69@6B-707537BDDDB75@@85
>
> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1210:18926:75163 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG
>
> @CCFFFFFHHHHHJJJHFDDD@77BDDDDB077007@B###########

From this we can see that `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` appeared twice, but I want to print only once.  how can I do that?

**Final output file**

> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1107:20386:6577 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC
>
> +
>
> CCCFFFFFHGHHHJIJHFDDDB173@8815BDDB###############
>
> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1114:5718:53821 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> +
>
> ;@?DBD<@@FFHHH<
>
> @DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1210:18926:75163 1:N:0:TTAGGC
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG
>
> +
>
> @CCFFFFFHHHHHJJJHFDDD@77BDDDDB077007@B

Comment: What is it with you biologist.. always post the worst formatted questions! You need to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to understand how the formatting works on Stackoverflow and http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking on asking a question.

Comment: sorry for this!next time won't do that

Comment: You have asked 14 questions over the last couple of months and all of them where terrible formatted and had to be completely overhauled *(mostly by me it seems)*. If you expect the community to help you then the least you can do is properly formatting your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a strong reason to do this yourself, use [Biopython](http://www.biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO).

fasta:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGG
```

fastq (based on yours but not identical because your output was badly formatted):

```
@DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1107:20386:6577 1:N:0:TTAGGC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC
+
CCCFFFFFHGHHHJIJHFDDDB173@8815BDDB###############
@DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1114:5718:53821 1:N:0:TTAGGC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
CCCFFFFFHGHHHJIJHFDDDB173@8815BDDB###############
@DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1209:10703:35361 1:N:0:TTAGGC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
@@@FFFFFHGHHHGIJHFDDDDDBDD69@6B-707537BDDDB75@@85
@DH1DQQN1:269:C1UKCACXX:1:1210:18926:75163 1:N:0:TTAGGC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG
+
@CCFFFFFHHHHHJJJHFDDD@77BDDDDB077007@B###########
```

Code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open("fasta") as fh:
    fasta = fh.read().splitlines()

seen = set()

for record in SeqIO.parse(open('fastq'), 'fastq'):
    seq = str(record.seq)
    if seq in fasta and seq not in seen:
        seen.add(seq)
        print record.format('fastq')
```

---

**EDIT**: The above prints records in the order of the fastq file, not the fasta file. If order is not important, you should use that method. Otherwise, you can add the records to a dictionary where the key is their index in the FASTA file, and print them all in the end, sorting the dictionary:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys

with open("fasta") as fh:
    fasta = fh.read().splitlines()

seen = set()
records = {}

for record in SeqIO.parse(open('fastq'), 'fastq'):
    seq = str(record.seq)
    if seq in fasta and seq not in seen:
        seen.add(seq)
        records[fasta.index(seq)] = record

for record in sorted(records):
    sys.stdout.write(records[record].format('fastq'))
```

(Here I also use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`, to avoid the extra newlines.)

Comment: I just want to print the first line of fasta file once in the fastq file@paulo Almeida

Comment: That's not what you have in your "Final output file". You should have a sample of desired output in the question (I don't understand what you mean by "print the first line of fasta file once in the fastq file"). In any case, once you have the records in Biopython objects you can print only what you want.

Comment: in the final output file i mentioned the first line appeared only once!it means i have repeated lines of same sequence in fastq file and i want to print the first one with bottom and top lines @paulo Alimeida

Comment: That's what this code does; it prints that line only once (every sequence that's been printed is stored so it doesn't get printed twice).

Comment: @abh,My original code didn't order the sequences according to the fasta file, now it does.

Comment: I am using the above bio python code but it is very slow!how i can run this faster(because my file is huge)@paulo Almeida

Comment: Check [this answer on BioStar](http://www.biostars.org/p/10353/) for faster solutions.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want a fastq with only unique sequences?

This is a horribly inefficient way to do it but it should work. It stores your fastq file as a list so hopefully its not too big. It will only throw out duplicate sequences, not quality scores or anything.

```
fastqFile = list(open(fastq))
out = []
output = open('output.fastq', 'at')

for lineNum, line in enumerate(fastqFile):
    if lineNum < 4:
        out.append(line)
        output.write(line)
    else:
        if line not in out and lineNum % 4 != 3:
            output.write(fastqFile[lineNum - 1])
            output.write(line)
            output.write(fastqFile[lineNum + 1])
            output.write(fastqFile[lineNum + 2])
            out.append(fastqFile[lineNum - 1])
            out.append(line)
            out.append(fastqFile[lineNum + 1])
            out.append(fastqFile[lineNum + 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I knew what you're trying to say, so here's my code. It will only take the first occurrence of the fasta sequence, as requested. This probably isn't the best way to do it, but I'm new at python.

```
# open the file into a list
fasta = open('fasta1.fa', 'r').read().splitlines()
fastq = open('fastq1.fq', 'r').read().splitlines()

# get rid of headers
# if headers important, please indicate in example
fastaseq = [s for s in fasta if not any('>' in t for t in s)]

# get rid of whitespace
fastaseq = filter(None, fastaseq)
fastq = filter(None, fastq)

# new list
newfastq = []

# go through each item in your fasta list
# if it matches, get the line above and below
# put in the new list
for fa in fastaseq:
    if fa in fastq:
        ind = fastq.index(fa)
        printblock = fastq[ind-1:ind+2]
    elif fa not in fastq:
        printblock = []
    if printblock:
        newfastq.append(printblock)

# print everything to file  
with open('fastq2.fq', 'w') as f:
    for block in newfastq:
        for item in block:
            f.writelines(item + '\n')
```